# Metro Form remove title bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have small project. 
I would like to use MetroFramework for my project. When I create new form I get new Metro form. In form title is form text. When I remove title text I have 60px padding in top. Please help me how can i remove it and put elements top of the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to remove the title bar.

This can be done by selecting the `None` option in `FormBorderStyle` property under Form properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should set false the value of the DisplayHeader in the form properties section

[image: im]